# Performing both layout and render transform results in wrong output

Tags: c#, wpf, rotatetransform, scaletransform, layouttransform

I just want to rotate an image hence I am performing layout transform(rotate transform) instead of render transform. Since layout transform rotate the image as expected (image gets fit into the new size). Also I want to flip the image, for that using render transform (scale transform). Both works fine when doing separately. When I rotate after flipping, image not positioned properly and vice versa case also.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="0" SizeChanged="Grid1_SizeChanged" >

    <Image x:Name="image1"  Source="Images/butterfly.jpg"   />          

</Grid>

private void Flip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int scaleX = -1;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
     scaleX = -1;
    else
     scaleX = 1;

    grid1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform();
    scale.ScaleX = scaleX;
    grid1.RenderTransform = scale;
    i++;
}

private void Rotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    grid1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();
    rotate.Angle = angle;
    grid1.LayoutTransform = rotate;
    angle += 90;
}
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCUCf.png)
[Rotation after flipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVPWR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use a TransformGroup for the LayoutTransform. It should have a RotateTransform and a ScaleTransform child element. By changing the order in which the child transforms are declared, you can control if the image is first rotated and then flipped, or vice versa.

```
<Image Source="Images/butterfly.jpg">
    <Image.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale"/>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

The Button Click handlers wouldn't need to do more than this:

```
private void RotateButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rotate.Angle += 90;
}

private void FlipButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scale.ScaleX *= -1;
}
```

Comment: This is ok....but for performing rotate transform only, I need layout transform since the image has to fit...for scale transform, it can be achieved with render transform itself.... Will this cause extra performance issue since layout transform will undergo measure pass... In some cases If I perform only scale transform..in that case this will additionally undergo measure and arrange.....Is there any other alternative

Comment: Why are you worrying about this? You don't flip the image 100 times a second.